# System's Version of Python is not up to date

Tags: python, macos, matlab

sorry if this is not the right stack for this question, but I wasn't sure which one to put it in. I have two problem:

The first problem is that when I type "python" into the terminal of my mac, it returns that I have python 2.7. However, I have installed python 3, so why does it show that?

Next, I need to install the matlab engine api for python. I look on the website, and it says to do so, I need to type:

cd "matlabroot/extern/engines/python"
python setup.py install

When I do this, it says no such directory found. Does anyone know what directory I can find this? I have looked all over in my computer (particularly in user library) for matlabroot, but I can't find it.

Comment: And if you type `python3`? Have you looked into virtual environments?

Comment: @jonrsharpe If I type python3, then the terminal says:

Comment: name 'python3' is not defined

Comment: Then you have not correctly installed Python 3. To get a Python development setup on OS X, run through e.g. https://hackercodex.com/guide/python-development-environment-on-mac-osx/

Comment: ok, will go through that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After reading the docs it seems that "matlabroot" is the path to the downloaded API.

In order to install the MATLAB API you have to download the setup files first.

Then navigate to the folder in terminal and run:

```
python setup.py
```

EDIT: installing python3 on a mac can be a pain. I recommend installing Anaconda to make your life a bit easier.